# Apply same selection (cut) to multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

My question is about making selections in `pandas` (python.)

As you know, one can apply a `selection` (or 'cut') to a dataframe by doing

```
df = df[df.area > 10]
```

if you wanted to (say) select all rows whose column value of `area` was greater than `10`. But suppose you have many dataframes, and you'd like to eventually apply this cut to all of them. It would be nice to do something like

```
cut = dataframe.area > 10
```

and then somehow be able to do

```
df = df[cut]
```

Obviously given the strategy above it won't work because `cut` refers to a specific dataframe. But is there a way to approximate this behavior?

That is, is it possible to define a `cut` that refers to no dataframe in particular and can be applied as `df = df[cut]`?

Comment: See the [query() Use Cases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-use-cases) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can get something similar

```
cut = lambda df: df[df.area > 10]
cut(df)
```

Per @root

```
cut = 'area > 10'
df.query(cut)
```

Per @ayhan

```
cut = lambda x: x.area > 10
df[cut]
```

---

#### Timing

***100 rows***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, 100), columns=['area'])
```

[image]

***1,000,000 rows***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, 1000000), columns=['area'])
```

[image]

Comment: So I misunderstood. In 0.18.0 you can do this too: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#method-chaininng-improvements (I mean just `cut = lambda df: df.area > 10` and `df[cut]`

Comment: @ayhan brilliant!  Stored in the memory banks.

Comment: @ayhan That's beautiful.